# div background-color doesn't work

Tags: css, html

I have been coding a website using html and css, and recently I've come to need a div element with a background color. I put in `background-color: gray;`, but that didn't work. I used the inspect element feature of Google Chrome, and it says that Chrome doesn't recognize the element. I used the same feature in Firefox, and it fails to recognize the css element either. The div contains three floating sections, but it uses `overflow: auto`, so that is not the problem. Can someone explain to me why I can't add background color to my divs?

html:

```
<div id="main">
        <header>
        <h1>LOGO</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" title="About">About</a>
            <a href="features.html" title="Features">Features</a>
            <a href="specs.html" title="Specifications">Specs</a>
            <a href="updates.html" title="Updates">Updates</a>
            <a href="contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        </header>

        <section class="left">
        <h2>NEWS</h2>
        <p>Itate eaquid quodit, utem dolorenihit ullore ides est faccum simaiorrum accaerf erfercim voloremod ut volectem con cus, temoluptatur as disquatent.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="right">
        <h2>SOMETHING</h2>
        <p>Itate eaquid quodit, utem dolorenihit ullore ides est faccum simaiorrum accaerf erfercim voloremod ut volectem con cus, temoluptatur as disquatent.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="right">
        <h2>SOMETHING</h2>
        <p>Itate eaquid quodit, utem dolorenihit ullore ides est faccum
simaiorrum accaerf erfercim voloremod ut volectem con cus,
temoluptatur as disquatent.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#main {
    backgound: gray;
    layer-background: gray;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px dashed black;

    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
}

section {
    background-color: green;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 5px;
    padding 10px;

    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please post the element's HTML and CSS (with selector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this part of your CSS:

```css
#main {
    backgound: gray;
    layer-background: gray;

    /* .. */
}
```

`backgound` should be `background`, and `layer-background` is not a CSS property.

With those mistakes fixed, [what you have works](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/U7AKJ/).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'm so ashamed. Typos will get me every time. `layer-background` was something I found on the internet that said would fix it.

Comment: Typos happen sometimes. [Validating your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) would have helped you to spot it.

Comment: @thePurpleMonkey [background-color](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-color) would be more color specific, as [background](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background) has wider range. But I think what you use is a question of personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling of background is incorrect. The correct spelling is **background** and try giving an Hex code other than using a color name.